# I wrote a rake task which executes from command line and not from cronjob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I wrote a rake task which executes from command line and not from cronjob.

I wrote a task which internally calls model method,
so suppose my task name is dataimport so if I call as

```
rake db:dataimport
```

it works, and create records in database.
But when I want execute it for every 10 seconds I putin crontab as

```
* * * * * sleep 10; cd $APP_DIR/lib/tasks; rake db:dataimport
```

this doesn't work.Any suggestions on this.

Comment: *this doesn't work* any errors? trace? or something?

Comment: Where can I see errors, as this is `cronjob`, which is executing code from rake task. errors are not getting logged in `production.log`

Comment: What about `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` ? Have you see something about you task? Cronjob do not post the result of job to the rails logs, you should look at system logs.

Comment: yes done that, `Jul 15 13:03:01 app-ded-1 /USR/SBIN/CRON[13217]: (app) CMD (sleep 10; cd $APP_DIR/lib/tasks; rake db:dataimport)`, it shows something like this with many lines, no errors

Comment: I suggest you read [`debugging crontab`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883069/debugging-crontab) this article can help you to resolve issue.

Comment: It could be an environment issue.  Do you use something like rvm or rbenv?

Comment: @ihaztehcodez I am not using any of them, it's ruby directly

Answer (score 0):

For rake commands to execute, you need to set PATH variable in your crontab file

If you are using ubuntu linux then first execute 'crontab -e' command and then
add the following line

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

at the top of the file.