# How to install cron with debugging enabled?

Tags: cron, debian

I like to debug a crontabs file which shows unclear behaviour and cron has the `-x` flag. However, running `cron -f -x proc` gives me

```
this program was compiled without debugging enabled
```

It is a debian system. Any advice on how to install a cron package with debugging enabled is highly appreciated. Could not find any advice online yet.

Comment: `-x` is to debug cron. To debug the cron program. For cron developers, so they will compile it with such support. I think you are looking how to debug the job of cron. Check configuration, and logs. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883069/debugging-crontab-jobs

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The man page actually names different options, like `be verbose about parsing individual crontab lines`, which sound also useful to end users. If it was only for development, I would not have expected a command line argument but simple compiler flags, not visible to end users.